# How to get values from a table without duplicate values

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table like this :

```
id -  phones - group_id

0  ---   11------- 1

1  ---   22------- 2

2  ---   12------- 1

3  ---   11------- 1

4  ---   45------- 1

5  ---   44--------1
```

Now, How can I get these values ?

11,12,45,44

for example : ".... `where group_id=1`"

I Google it can't find exact solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
select distinct phones from table where group_id = 1
```

Should work